# Difference between client-server web apps and websites

Tags: web, web-applications, web-architecture

I am wondering: why we use to split a web app into a client (JavaScript, CSS or even a framework like React or angular) and a server (PHP)?
Why it is preferable to do so instead of simply going on a website that includes PHP and HTML all together?

Answer (score 0):

scalability and private storage. Hosting your own server side framework allows for huge application and privacy. The storage of html is minimal at best so it is much safer to have your own backend stuff. especially for enterprise software.